# Hidden layer with zoom level

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layers, zoom

I would like to display some layer according to max and min zoom levels. I tried with the method min / max zoom and resolution but without success.

I specify that I use vector tiles.

Here is my code:

```
// Courbe de niveau (Mbtiles)
var layerIso = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
  source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
    format: new ol.format.MVT(),
    url: 'http://localhost:8085/data/courbe50/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf',
    minResolution: 10
  }),
  style: function (feature, resolution){
      var ISO100 =  new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#1c8b00' })
      });
      var ISOERROR =  new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#ba4646' })
      });

      if (feature.get('elevation')  % 200 === 0 ) {
        return [ISO100];
      }
      else {
        return [ISOERROR];
      }
  },
});

map.addLayer(layerIso);
```

Comment: What type of character do you talk about? The min and max resolution needs only one parameter. I can not understand why this method has no effect on my data